# Yii : CJuidialog and iframe

Tags: yii

I'm using Yii framework. I need to create dialog using iframe. How can i create CJuidialog in iframe? If you have some experience with it, please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

> I am using CjuiDialog For creating playlist 
>   In My Layout (playlist Button)

```
`<a href="#" id="addavtoplaylist">Add To playList</a>`
```

> By Clicking Above Button id refer the following code

In View Page

```
  $('#addavtoplaylist').live('click',function(){
            $('#cru-frame').attr('src','".Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("playlist/add",array('id'=>$this->model->av_id))."'); 
            $('#cru-dialog').dialog('open');  
            return false;                        
        });
```

> add the dialog code in the same page

```
<?php
//--------------------- begin new code --------------------------
   // add the (closed) dialog for the iframe
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'cru-dialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Add To Play List',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,
        'width'=>550,
        'height'=>300,
        'close'=>'js:function(){                             
        }',
    ),
    ));
?>
<iframe id="cru-frame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<?php

$this->endWidget();
//--------------------- end new code --------------------------
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your view file

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'mydialog',
// additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
),
));
echo 'dialog content here';
$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
// the link that may open the dialog
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
```